# Disable wheel selector on iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

What is the easiest way to disable the wheel selector that appears on mobile Safari when a user activates a `<select>` element?

I have styled the `<select>` and `<option>` elements myself, and I would prefer that the user interacts directly, rather than with the scroll supplied by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you could probably `preventDefault()` on click and touch events on the `<select>`, however it's not clear how you would then make it actually usable. So, you may want to avoid using a select element at all once you detect an iOS device.

You could employ some widget collection such as [this one](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html). It can be used to implement dropdown menus or any other kind of menu, and does not open the big wheel thing on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the wheel selector on mobile Safari.

Comment: As of 2022, Apple disabled it permanently!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 this is no longer an issue. Hooray! They finally got rid of the wheel selector. In iOS Safari the select element is now a normal list, similar to Android. I've been waiting years for this issue to be addressed, the wheel selector was awful UX and is finally gone. iOS Safari is actually a good browser now.